# How to convert twitter curl request into javascript? ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, api, curl, twitter

I am developing an APP using Javascript which I am using Twitter API. Now to make a GET request I need the bearer token; however to get the bearer token I need to make a cURL request.

```
curl -u '<API key>:<API secret key>' \
--data 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'
```

Any Idea of how can I convert this cURL request into Javascript? Thanks

Comment: You need to route these requests through your backend, which as opposed to in-browser-JS can a) keep the secret an actual secret b) do curl easily

Comment: So I cant code the cURL into a function in the Javascript? I am asking because I am really new to cURL.

Comment: JavaScript supports curl type requests to a server ([`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)) but a) unless the *server* allows requests from other domains, the browser will block them (keyword CORS) and b) all JS code is visible to the user, so you will expose your API secret